# Kaa C application from raspberry pi

Tags: c, kaa

I am trying to build a C application on my raspberry pi to send log to the kaa server, I am following the C documentation from the official website.
I have managed to do this before using java but now I am trying to do the same application but in C. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <kaa/kaa.h>
#include <kaa/platform/kaa_client.h>
#include <kaa/kaa_error.h>
#include <extensions/logging/kaa_logging.h>
#include <kaa/platform-impl/common/ext_log_upload_strategies.h>

#define LOG_UPLOAD_THRESHOLD 5

typedef struct {
    kaa_client_t *kaa_client;
    kaa_string_t * uuid;
    kaa_string_t * proximity;
    int32_t major;
    int32_t minor;
    int32_t measured_power;
    int32_t rssi;
    double accuracy;
} log_context;

static void sendLog(void *context)
{
    if (context == NULL) {
            return;
    }

    log_context * log_details_context = context;

    kaa_logging_beacon_t *log_record = kaa_logging_beacon_create();

    if (!log_record) {
            printf("Failed to create log record\r\n");
            kaa_client_stop(log_details_context->kaa_client);
            return;
    }

    log_record->uuid = log_details_context->uuid;
    log_record->major = log_details_context->major;
    log_record->minor = log_details_context->minor;
    log_record->measured_power = log_details_context->measured_power;
    log_record->rssi = log_details_context->rssi;
    log_record->accuracy = log_details_context->accuracy;
    log_record->proximity = log_details_context->proximity;

    kaa_error_t error = kaa_logging_add_record(
            kaa_client_get_context(log_details_context->kaa_client)->log_collector,
            log_record, NULL);

    if (error) {
            printf("Failed to add log record, error code %d\r\n");
            kaa_client_stop(log_details_context->kaa_client);
            return;
    }

    // log_record->destroy(log_record);

    kaa_client_stop(log_details_context->kaa_client);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double accuracy;
    kaa_string_t * uuid;
    kaa_string_t * proximity;
    int32_t major, minor, measured_power, rssi;

    if (argc != 8) {
            printf("Number of arguments are not right");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    uuid = argv[1];
    if (sscanf (argv[2], "%i", &major) != 1) {
            printf("Major is not an integer");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf (argv[3], "%i", &minor) != 1) {
            printf("Minor is not an integer");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf (argv[4], "%i", &measured_power) != 1) {
            printf("Measured power is not an integer");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf (argv[5], "%i", &rssi) != 1) {
            printf("RSSI is not an integer");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (sscanf (argv[6], "%lf", &accuracy) != 1) {
            printf("Accuracy is not a double");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    proximity = argv[7];
    /*
       printf("UUID = %s\n", uuid);
       printf("major = %d\n", major);
       printf("minor = %d\n", minor);
       printf("measured power = %d\n", measured_power);
       printf("RSSI = %d\n", rssi);
       printf("accuracy = %lf\n", accuracy);
       printf("proximity = %s\n", proximity);
     */


    /**
     * Initialize Kaa client.
     */
    kaa_client_t *kaa_client = NULL;
    kaa_error_t error = kaa_client_create(&kaa_client, NULL);

    if (error) {
            printf("Failed to create Kaa client\r\n", error);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    log_context log_details_context;
    log_details_context.kaa_client = kaa_client;
    log_details_context.uuid = uuid;
    log_details_context.major = major;
    log_details_context.minor = minor;
    log_details_context.measured_power = measured_power;
    log_details_context.rssi = rssi;
    log_details_context.proximity = proximity;
    log_details_context.accuracy = accuracy;

    void *log_upload_strategy_context = NULL;
    error = ext_log_upload_strategy_create(kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client),
                                           &log_upload_strategy_context, KAA_LOG_UPLOAD_VOLUME_STRATEGY);

    if (error) {
            printf("Failed to create log upload strategy, error code %d\r\n", error);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    error = ext_log_upload_strategy_set_threshold_count(log_upload_strategy_context,
                                                        LOG_UPLOAD_THRESHOLD);

    if (error) {
            printf("Failed to set threshold log record count, error code %d\r\n", error);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    error = kaa_logging_set_strategy(kaa_client_get_context(kaa_client)->log_collector,
                                     log_upload_strategy_context);

    if (error) {
            printf("Failed to set log upload strategy, error code %d\r\n", error);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /**
     * Start Kaa client main loop.
     */
    error = kaa_client_start(kaa_client, sendLog,
                             &log_details_context, 0);

    if (error) {
            printf("Failed to start Kaa client, error code %d\r\n", error);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    /**
     * Destroy Kaa client.
     */
    kaa_client_destroy(kaa_client);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am getting the following output on my console:

```
2017/02/05 0:24:47 [INFO] [kaa.c:149] (0) - Kaa SDK version 0.10.0, commit hash

2017/02/05 0:24:47 [DEBUG] [kaa_logging.c:383] (0) - Initialized log collector with log storage {0x2037c40}, log upload strategy {0x2037c78}

2017/02/05 0:24:47 [INFO] [kaa_client.c:471] (0) - Log collector init completed

2017/02/05 0:24:47 [INFO] [kaa_client.c:155] (0) - Kaa client created

2017/02/05 0:24:47 [INFO] [kaa_client.c:295] (0) - Starting Kaa client...

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is the debug info I got from gdb

```
Starting program: /home/delvebyte/projects/beacon-scanner-pi/kaa-application-c/build/kaa-app UUID 0 1 -65 -72 0.873637383 near
2017/02/06 16:20:26 [INFO] [kaa.c:149] (0) - Kaa SDK version 0.10.0, commit hash 
2017/02/06 16:20:26 [DEBUG] [kaa_logging.c:383] (0) - Initialized log collector with log storage {0x5555557a14d0}, log upload strategy {0x5555557a1ab0}
2017/02/06 16:20:26 [INFO] [kaa_client.c:471] (0) - Log collector init completed
2017/02/06 16:20:26 [INFO] [kaa_client.c:155] (0) - Kaa client created
2017/02/06 16:20:26 [INFO] [kaa_client.c:295] (0) - Starting Kaa client...

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
106 ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
#1  0x00005555555658c2 in kaa_string_get_size (data=0x7fffffffe256)
at /home/delvebyte/projects/beacon-scanner-pi/kaa-application-c/kaa/src/kaa/kaa_common_schema.c:117
#2  0x000055555556220d in kaa_logging_beacon_get_size (data=0x5555557a1b70)
at /home/delvebyte/projects/beacon-scanner-pi/kaa-application-c/kaa/src/kaa/gen/kaa_logging_gen.c:63
#3  0x00005555555700f4 in kaa_logging_add_record (self=0x5555557a0bc0, 
entry=0x5555557a1b70, log_info=0x0)
at /home/delvebyte/projects/beacon-scanner-pi/kaa-application-c/kaa/src/extensions/logging/kaa_logging.c:514
#4  0x0000555555556dcf in sendLog (context=0x7fffffffdd30)
at /home/delvebyte/projects/beacon-scanner-pi/kaa-application-c/src/kaa-application.c:46
#5  0x0000555555557b48 in kaa_client_start (kaa_client=0x5555557a0010, 
external_process=0x555555556cf0 <sendLog>, 
external_process_context=0x7fffffffdd30, max_delay=0)
at /home/delvebyte/projects/beacon-scanner-pi/kaa-application-c/kaa/src/kaa/platform-impl/posix/kaa_client.c:300
#6  0x0000555555557153 in main (argc=8, argv=0x7fffffffde68)
at /home/delvebyte/projects/beacon-scanner-pi/kaa-application-c/src/kaa-application.c:160
(gdb)
```

Comment: Did you see the [troubleshooting guide](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Troubleshooting+guide)? Is it possible to test or debug it it in a sandbox?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the platform so I don't know what debugging tools you have available but if you have some way of printing, logging or displaying a number, and debugger, or sandbox aren't working, you can just put a printf() or log() statement in various places and use those to triage it down to an offending line usually. Debugger can be easier, once you learn it, and it's usually worth the effort to master debugger basics if available.

Comment: Well, based on the console output, it looks like the seg fault is occurring in `kaa_client_start`, so expect something about the setup is out of spec.Therefore the suggestions to use `printf` debugging aren't helpful unless you're able to add them in library code. If there is symbol info for kaa and you can get a stack trace from the core dump (for example with a debugger), it might point you to the error.

Comment: The error happens in this line  kaa_error_t error = kaa_logging_add_record(
                kaa_client_get_context(log_details_context->kaa_client)->log_collector,
                log_record, NULL);

Comment: Compile with `-DKAA_MAX_LOG_LEVEL=6` and `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` CMake options. Then run the application in `gdb`. As the application receives `SIGSEGV` (Segmentation fault), issue `bt` in the `gdb` command line. This will show the call stack prior to the crash. Then update your question with full log and backtrace so that I could help you to figure out the problem.

Comment: @RostakaGmfun Thanks so much for the advice that was ao helpful, I edited my original post with all debug info please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in treating kaa_string_t * as char *, when I get a better look at the kaa library I found that kaa_string_t is a structure which has char * inside it, so I used this function to initialize the variable kaa_string_move_create and that was it